# Should i enable bios legacy support for win11

Tags: windows

My windows 11 machine suddenly went of and my hard drive I no longer detected by bios. It says no hard drive installed. sometimes it boots into q blue screen telling me that it ran into an inaccessible boot device. Should I enable legacy support in bios to attempt a fix?. Will it hurt anything?

Comment: Windows 11 needs UEFI BIOS.  I suggest getting the manufacturer's Hardware Test App on bootable USB and test your hardware to see if the disk has developed an issue.

Comment: I figured thanks John. Do you think this could be a result of a loose connection?

Comment: @NobleEugene - You will have to tell us.  Windows 11 is incompatible with Legacy mode. Enabling Legacy Mode isn't a solution to your problem.  However, unless the connection was lose, and you were moving the machine it's unlikely something like a cable connection is the problem.  **What is more likely the HDD just simply failed.**

Comment: Agreed - installing an operating system upgrade is heavy on disk operations, so your disk seems to have already been failing before the upgrade which was the last straw.

Comment: Do you think this could be a result of a loose connection?  ........ Possibly or more likely a failing hard drive.

Comment: Yeah John, hardrive turned out to be dead. Read 20 Percent on sentinel